# How can I get my C Shell to recognize that this is a command?

Tags: c, fork, execvp

I am very new at C but am currently working on creating a C program to serve as a shell interface. It is supposed to accept commands and then execute each command in a separate process. I am currently stuck trying to get C to recognize that it is a command. I am unsure how to do this, and can't seem to find any useful examples.

Here is my code, it is saying that everything is not a valid command ("no cmd"). Does anyone have any idea why this would be occurring? Is C not able to recognize it is a command in the execvp() function or do I need to implement something for that specific purpose?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80
/* 80 chars per line per command */

int main(void) {
  //char *args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1];
    char *args = calloc(MAX_LINE, (MAX_LINE/2 +1));
    const size_t sz = MAX_LINE;
    pid_t pid;
  /* command line (of 80) has max of 40 arguments*/
  int should_run = 1;

  while (should_run) {
    printf("osh>"); //beginning of command line
        fgets(args, sz, stdin); //gets the stdin

        char *token = strtok(args, " \n"); //supposed to break str if it has a space or line and recognize there are 2 commands
        printf("%s\n", token);
        
        token = strtok(NULL," \n");
        printf("%s\n", token);
            pid_t parent = getpid();
      pid = fork(); //forking child
            if(pid == 0){ //if forking occurred
                int status = execvp(&args[0], &args); //status of input, is it a command?
                printf("%d", status);
                printf("forked!");
                if(status == -1) { //if cmd err, print
                    printf("no cmd");
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    printf("line will be printed");
                }
                return 0;
            }
        fflush(stdout); //flush
        /*

   
    * After reading user input, the steps are :
    * 1: fork a child process
    * 2: the child process will invoke execvp()
    * 3: parent process waits for the child to exit before       
    continuing
    */
  }

  exit(0);
  /**
  return to the operating system:
    -exit this process
    -flush all
  */

  
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Are you trying to get the exit code of the child process?

Comment: `printf("%s\n", token);` You do not check if `token` is `NULL`.

Comment: Your `&args` is not suitable for "an array of pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the new program.  The first argument, by convention, should point to the file name associated with the file being executed.  The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer." See [execvp](https://www.manpagez.com/man/3/execvp/) for details on the function parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for the `exec` family of functions, you'll note that the functions only return if the `exec` failed.  That's because `exec`, when successful, completely replaces the calling process with the invoked program.

What you need to do is, from the parent process (i.e., the one that got a positive value returned from `fork`), wait on the child process via `waitpid`.

```c
pid_t pid;

pid = fork();
if ( pid < 0 ) {
    // Handle the error.
}
else if ( pid == 0 ) {
    execvp(&args[0], &args);
    // The fact that we've reached this line means that execvp failed.
    exit(1);
}
else {
    int status;

    while ( waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != pid ) {} // We need this loop in case waitpid gets interrupted by a signal.

    // status doesn't equal the return value of the child process.  We need to extract that with macros.
    if ( WIFEXITED(status) ) {
        printf("Child process exited with code %i\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
    else {
        printf("Child process was terminated by signal number %i\n", WTERMSIG(status));
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, consider using `spawn` / `posix_spawn`.

Comment: The disadvantage of waiting solely for the last child executed is that if there are background jobs running, they'll remain zombies until they are waited for.  Granted, that is unlikely to be a problem just yet, but it will probably become one eventually, at least if the shell is worked on long enough.

Comment: Alternatively, reject the POSIX spawn code as the spawn of the devil.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, that's true.  However, I just wanted to show how `exec`/`waitpid` work together.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Whyso? The advantage of spawn is that it handles the rest of the housekeeping for you. I never liked the concept of `fork + exec` because it breaks assumptions about objects that should only have one owning process (e.g. file handles) as well as orphaning global memory referenced by thread-local-storage in the parent process.

Comment: @Dai: Because of the cloud of housekeeping functions you have to call to get the child to process I/O redirection for pipes and file descriptors, etc.  It's much simpler to write the code in the child before the `exec*()` than to work out which of the spawn functions need to be called to get the job done.   There are about 20 functions related to [`posix_spawn()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html). It isn't clear that you can set the environment differently for the spawned process even with that magnificent supporting cast. Shells need to do that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah yes, for a shell process, that makes sense

Comment: The list of functions is too long to fit into a single comment.  It includes: • posix_spawnattr_destroy()
• posix_spawnattr_getflags()
• posix_spawnattr_getpgroup()
• posix_spawnattr_getschedparam()
• posix_spawnattr_getschedpolicy()
• posix_spawnattr_getsigdefault()
• posix_spawnattr_getsigmask()
• posix_spawnattr_init()
• posix_spawnattr_setflags()
• posix_spawnattr_setpgroup()
• posix_spawnattr_setschedparam()
• posix_spawnattr_setschedpolicy()
• posix_spawnattr_setsigdefault()
• posix_spawnattr_setsigmask()
…

Comment: …• posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose()
• posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2()
• posix_spawn_file_actions_addopen()
• posix_spawn_file_actions_destroy()
• posix_spawn_file_actions_init()
• posix_spawn()
• posix_spawnp()
—— What about if you want to reset EUID or EGID inside a SUID or SGID program?  Tinker with group memberships?   There are quite a lot of things that cannot be done with the POSIX spawn system that can be done with `fork() + exec*()`.  Not to mention things that can be done with `fork()` without also using `exec*()`.